# Create Custom events in Namespaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create custom events in a javascript NameSpace, but i dont know if its possible.

I have a namespace like this:

```
NAMESPACE = {

   var1 : 'value',
   var2 : 'value',

   initiate : function() {
      console.log('initiate');
   },

   clear : function(arg) {
      console.log('clear');
   }

   fail : function() {
       // Here i need to trigger the error event..
   }

}
```

That creates events using this method:

```
var myEvent = new CustomEvent("errorX", {
  data: {
    param: "value"
  }
});

document.dispatchEvent(myEvent);

// In document.ready...
$(document).on('errorX', function(e) {
   console.log(e);
});
```

This works, but I need to attach the `addEventlistener` to the `document` and I would like to attach this to the namespace object, like:

```
$(NAMESPACE).on('errorX', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

It this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) method:

```
$(NAMESPACE).on('errorX', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});

$(NAMESPACE).triggerHandler("errorX");
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Enq9h/

Comment: @Zenth you don't need `.dispatchEvent` at all, jQuery doesn't use it. It uses `.triggerHandler`/`.trigger`

Comment: I update your example trying to make similar to my code, but dont get the event params.. possible reason?

Comment: @Zenth you can pass arguments in the second argument as an array: http://jsfiddle.net/Enq9h/3/ I also recommend `.triggerHandler` over `. trigger` because it's optimized for custom events on normal objects.

Comment: OK, its possible to do this without jQuery? (Using only jquery in the "$(NAMESPACE).on('errorX..")

Comment: @Zenth yes if you make your custom event library or use existing one. But if you are already using jQuery you might as well use it.